# full keyboard controls when running ubuntu shell in chromeos tab

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, google-chrome-os, crouton-os

when running ubuntu cli in a tab (a chrome tab in chrome os) using crouton, i can't press `control w` to search in the `nano` text editor. It triggers the *close window* command instead for chrome. How can I disable this? With a GUI installed for Ubuntu, I can run the program full screen and get total keyboard command capture. Is this impossible when running in a Chrome tab? Is there any way to get the cli out of the chrome tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome OS Download 'Crouton integration Extension' from Google Store

Chrome OS Download crouton from bottom link of Francois Beaufort

Chrome OS Open CROSH ...type crt + alt + t

Chrome OS type shell

Chrome OS type: sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t unity,extension

Chrome OS type: sudo startunity

Info & Links https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/JDVkXALPcNq